# Can I use x times big than?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

I know this is correct "My big brother is twice as big as me"

BUT

Can I say "My big brother is twice as big than me"?

Comment: You can say it and be understood, but it is incorrect.

Comment: What does it mean to be big? Tall?

Answer (score 0):

You’ll be understood, but your first example is more grammatical.

Also, you should use the subjective pronoun “I” instead of objective pronoun “me” because you wouldn’t say ”me am.”

Therefore, the sentence, “My big brother is twice as big as I am,” would be what you want to use.  Although, it does sound a bit awkward, and perhaps rephrasing it would thus be your best option.

Comment: Why do you think the subjective pronouns should be used? It's not the subject of the sentence! There's no rule in English that comparisons both use "I"!

Comment: There have been many threads on ELU saying that using "It is I", "I am taller than they", "Whom did you have paint your front room?" mean that your English is sadly out of date.

Comment: @curiousdannii If the sentence were to be absolutely complete, it’d be, “My big brother is twice as big as I am.” Hence, I would use “I” instead of “me.” I’m not saying he has to use the subjective pronoun while talking colloquially, but in formal discourse, I would definitely use “I am” or “I” instead of “me.” In any case, the sentence sounds rather awkward, and rewording it would thus be the best option.

Comment: So you'd say that "You are taller than me" is ungrammatical?

Comment: @curiousdannii  Yes.  The answers on this link explain it pretty well:  https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-He-is-taller-than-I-and-He-is-taller-than-me-from-grammar-point-of-view

Comment: In practice (almost) nobody would say "You are taller than I" unironically, they would either say "...than me" or "...than I am". Saying "...than I" without the "am" usually sounds dated (as noted by Edwin) or pretentious.

Comment: @nnnnnn Well I’d rather my formal writing sound dated than be ungrammatical, but everyone has their own opinion.  And I almost always say “I am” instead of just “I”.  But if I were limited to only “I” and “me” in a case like this, I’d always choose “I”.